# Calculating wind gradient du_dx, dv_dy using np.gradient

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the wind gradient given u-wind and v-wind. The u and v values have a 3d-array with the following shape:

u(122,9,9) such that u(time,latitude,longitude). The same applies for v.

I have also calculated the dx and dy values (in 2-d array for both lat and lon direction)

The sample of my code is as below at time 0 for example:

```
dudx = np.gradient(u[0,0,:], dx[0,0], edge_order=2)
dvdy = np.gradient(v[0,:,0], dy[0,0], edge_order=2)
```

I can then sum dudx and dvdy to get the gradient. I have a data that has already calculated the divergence, and upon comparing my calculation with the divergence data, i expected the values to be the same, but they're not. I can't seem to figure out where i went wrong besides using the np.gradient function incorrectly.

I would like to know if my methods above to calculate the gradient of u and v winds are correct.

Cheers.

Edit

The full code i am using to calculate the wind gradient is as below:

```
dqu_dx = np.zeros((122,9,9))
dqv_dy = np.zeros((122,9,9))


for i in range(122):
    for j in range(9):
        for k in range(9):
            dqu_dx[i,j,:] = np.gradient(dqu_18hr[i,j,:], dx[0,k], edge_order=2)
            dqv_dy[i,:,k] = np.gradient(dqv_18hr[i,:,k], dy[j,0], edge_order=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment on your question to ask for explanations because I don't have enough reputation, so I am forced to make some assumptions. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

I will assume that `dqu_18hr` and `dqv_18hr` are arrays storing the value of two different functions, u(t, y, x) and v(t, y, x). If I understand correctly you want to calculate du/dx and dv/dy.

I don't know what are the dx and dy values that you store in the arrays, also because you define them as 2D-arrays but use them as 1D-arrays. I will assume that `dx` and `dy` are coordinates of the points at which you computed u and v, and that the grid they produce is regular.

A first problem with your code is that you are passing a single scalar number as the second argument of np.gradient. When this is done, numpy assumes that this is the distance between points. However, this distance changes at every iteration. I can think of a quite convoluted case for which the definition of dx is such that this gives the correct result, but generally this is a mistake.

Another problem with the code is that it doesn't take advantage of numpy vectorization, using explicitly three for loops. This is extremely inefficient computationally.

I would suggest you the following code:

```
x = dx[0, :]  # or whatever is the correct definition
y = dy[:, 0]  # not enough info in the post to understand it

a = np.gradient(dqu_18hr, x, axis=2, edge_order=2)
b = np.gradient(dqv_18hr, y, axis=1, edge_order=2)
```

Please also notice that in your code x is associated to the axis 2 and y to the axis 1, which is absolutely legit but unusual so you might want to check if that's a mistake.